# How to map document with dynamic keys to a Spring MongoDb entity class

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document that can have dynamic key names:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51a29f6413dc992c24e0283e"),
"envinfo" : {
    "appName" : "MyJavaApp",
    "environment" : {
        "cpuCount" : 12,
        "heapMaxBytes" : 5724766208,
        "osVersion" : "6.2",
        "arch" : "amd64",
        "javaVendor" : "Sun Microsystems Inc.",
        "pid" : 44996,
        "javaVersion" : "1.6.0_38",
        "heapInitialBytes" : 402507520,
}
```

Here `envinfo` 's keys are not known in advance.
What is the best way to create an entity class in Spring Data Mongodb which will map this document?

Comment: are you saying that another document of the same collection will have _id and an embedded object similar to envinfo but called something else? like envinfo2?

Comment: what i mean is that the fields on envinfo are not known in advance. Here they are 'cpuCount', 'arch', etc, but they may be 'coreCount', or something else.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it. There may be other better ways.

Create a map of attributes and store the map in mongo.

```
public class Env {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private ObjectId id;
    @Field
    private Envinfo envinfo;

    public static class Envinfo {
       @Field
       private String appName;
       @Field
       private Map<String, String> attributes;
    }
}
```

If you know the keys in advance, you may add those attributes in Envinfo and keep those out of attributes map.

Comment: but wont the above expect a document like envinfo { appName: "name, attributes {} }. basically with the above, 'attributes' would need to be a subdocument of envinfo. also this doesnt take into account the fact that some keys might contain other sub documents.

Comment: it's mongodb, it doesn't expect anything other than id (unless you use spring annotation to make it a mandatory field). if there can be other subdocuments, then use "private Map<String, Object> attributes;", but then it becomes cumbersome and totally schema-less, which is not what mongo is made for. You should consider using a different persistence solution.

Comment: I ended up using something similar for my problem [how-to-aggregate-in-spring-data-mongo-db-a-nested-object-and-avoid-a-propertyException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913900/7747942). That might help someone looking to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I'll do.

```
class EnvDocuemnt {

    @Id
    private String id; //getter and setter omitted

    @Field(value = "envinfo")
    private BasicDBObject infos;

    public Map getInfos() {
        // some documents don't have any infos, in this case return null...
        if ( null!= infos)
            return infos.toMap();
        return null;
    }

    public void setInfos(Map infos) {
        this.infos = new BasicDBObject( infos );
    }

}
```

This way, `getInfos()` returns a `Map<String,Object>` you can explore with String keys when needed, and that can have nested Map.

For your dependencies, it is better not to expose the `BasicDBObject` field directly, so this can be used via interface in a code not including any MongoDb library.

Note that if there is some frequent accessed fields in envinfo, then it would be better to declare them as fields in your class, to have a direct accessor, and so not to spend to much time in browsing the map again and again.